# Texlive, Miktex, tex in Cygwin - are these redundant on Windows?

Tags: miktex, texlive, windows, cygwin

I have at least two Tex distributions installed on my Windows computer, and occasionally I use tex via Cygwin. I believe some of that is redundant:

Via Cygwin:

```
$where pdflatex
C:\cygwin64\bin\pdflatex
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
```

I don't know which of the two LaTeX distributions are called from my Windows environment, and whether Cygwin either uses a separate distribution or one of the above. What is a good way of finding out?

Comment: compile a document and look into the log-file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right that they are redundant.  Unless you are a developer who needs to test multiple distributions, you only need one.  In fact, having all three around could cause a problem when you run the wrong distribution’s executable.  Choose either the native TeX Live, or MikTeX, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the cygwin texlive almost exclusively (not the one you show which is the cygwin system tex, but rather the cygwin texlive from tug, so
`(C:\cygwin64)/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-cygwin/pdflatex`

You probably don't need both of these, but you should probably keep one.

```
C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
```

as they are both native windows ones. If you use texlive, you could update 2020 is a while ago, texlive 2022 is current (and parts of 2023 can be found in the source repositories)

If you use both the cygwin and windows commandlines it is convenient to have both binaries available as while it is possible to use a windows binary from cygwin, the virtual file paths are different and so you always have to mediate between cygwin's view of the current working directory and the windows view.

It is simplest just to install separately on windows and cygwin (and wsl if you use that) although if space is tight you can install all three binary formats (wsl uses linux texlive) in sibling directories that then share all fonts and latex packages etc.

personally I just have (several) cygwin versions installed (texlive 2020,2021,2022; cygwin system texlive; wsl linux texlive 2021) I don't have a windows tex installed, but I hardly ever use a windows commandline.